# HttpStatusCodeResult message limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, response

I'm trying to return a response message form the server:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(406, "bla bla")
```

And then display it:

```
.error(function (response) {
    $(elem).after("<b class=\"notif-msg\">" + response.statusText + "</b>");
```

And it works fine until I try to send more than "bla bla" and my message is no longer shown; instead I get some message saying "Error".

How do I get pass this limitation?

Comment: Please read the description of tags before using them. [tag:model-view-controller] is not meant for the ASP.Net implementation, but for the general concept.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC3 HttpStatusCodeResult StatusDescription - Specified argument was out of the range of valid values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877232/asp-net-mvc3-httpstatuscoderesult-statusdescription-specified-argument-was-out)

Comment: Don't use the reason phrase for this; return a body explaining what went wrong. If you do this in JSON format, JavaScript code on your HTML page can interpret this.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm actually getting "error" instead of the expected string

Comment: Because the string you try to set is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to encode your string, and make sure the encoded version doesn't exceed the size limit.

If you're using .net 4, you could use [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error you're receiving is "arguement out of range" then I believe the answer to this has been provided in [ASP.NET MVC3 HttpStatusCodeResult StatusDescription - Specified argument was out of the range of valid values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877232/asp-net-mvc3-httpstatuscoderesult-statusdescription-specified-argument-was-out)

Comment: Well it says it can't be longer than 255 chars but my length is 99 and I'm not getting any actual error (like in the other post) but the `response.statusText` is = to "error"

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult MyFunction()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return new ContentResult()
    {
        Content = "My message",
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    };
}
```

And Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MyFunction", "MyController")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { },
        error: function (error)
        {
            alert(error.responseText);
        },
        success: function () {}
    });
```