# Web Api Exception Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

In my app I am trying to use Exception handling. What I am trying to do is to create a separate class and extend it from *HttpResponseException*.

This is the code I have written until now,

```
public class ApiExceptions : HttpResponseException
{
    public ApiExceptions(string reason, HttpStatusCode code)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = code,
            ReasonPhrase = reason,
            Content = new StringContent(reason)
        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error,

```
'System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

I am really new at exception handling in c#. I would really appreciate the help in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following code should works

> : base(...)

If you omit the call to a base constructor it will call the default base constructor automatically and HttpResponseException doesn't have without arguments.

```
 public class ApiExceptions : HttpResponseException
        {
            public ApiExceptions(string reason, HttpStatusCode code):base(code)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = code,
                    ReasonPhrase = reason,
                    Content = new StringContent(reason)
                };
                throw new HttpResponseException(response);
            }
        }
```

anyway i'm not sure why you need to extend HttpResponseException

Comment: This is a great solution. Anyone using this in production should add a check that the reason string is not greater than 512 characters in length.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877267/3761486

Answer (score 3):

The `HttpResponseException` class [has two constructors defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception.httpresponseexception%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), both of which require a value:

```
HttpResponseException(HttpResponseMessage)
HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode)
```

Because your `ApiExceptions` class inherits from  `HttpResponseException`, it has to provide a compatible constructor. As all the class does is return the `HttpResponseException`, it doesn't seem necessary for it to inherit from that class at all.

Comment: can you provide an example on how to extend that class?

Comment: Why do you need to extend the class?

Comment: now that I am thinking it feels like I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to derived form HttpResponseException you should use a code similar to this: In the example is a customize exception that return BadRequest type exception and a custom message.

```
 public class HttpResponseBadRequestException: HttpResponseException
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Basic
    /// </summary>
    public HttpResponseBadRequestException()
        : this(string.Empty)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specific Constructor. Use this to send a Bad request exception
    /// with a custom message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be send in the response</param>
    public HttpResponseBadRequestException(string message)
        : base(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) {
            Content = new StringContent(message) })
    {
    }
}
```